# Are mutiple methods recommended when returning different types?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, return-type, generic-method

I'm returning values from an `Entity` object. Some of them are `String` typed and some are not. Right now, I did a quick solution as follows.

```
private String GetStringValue(Entity entity, String attribute, String substitute = "")
{
  if(entity.Contains(attribute)
    return entity[attribute] as String;
  return substitute;
}

private String GetIntValue(Entity entity, String attribute, int substitute = 0)
{
  if(entity.Contains(attribute)
    return entity[attribute] as int;
  return substitute;
}
```

Then I remembered that there's a syntax for generic typing (something like `<TypeX>`). My question is, however, if there's a point to start changing the existing code. I'll need to change the signature of the method in two places (return type and substitute type) but I fear that I'll need to do some complex coding **inside** the method as well.

On the other hand, I'd have a nice way to treat **all** the types possible (and I have a hunch we'll be working with more than strings and integers.

Comment: The second method should return `int`, right?

Comment: Also, does `as int` compile? `as` is only applicable to reference types, which `int` is not.

Comment: Sorry, should be `int` in the signature and `(int)` in the body. CTRL+C/V and manual edit, hehe. Good eyes. +1 for that alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right "something like" is the generic method. [Check out generic methods there.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
Next method looks good for your purpose.

```
   private  static T GetValue<T>(Entity entity, string attribute, T defaultValue)
        {
            if (!entity.Contains(attribute))
                return defaultValue;

            return  (T)entity[attribute];
        }
```

**EDIT:** updated according of the w0lf's comment.

Comment: `as T` will not work unless you put some constraints on what `T` can be. Here's some code that does something similar: http://pastebin.com/t3JbuJ2s

Comment: @w0lf it is depend on your entity. If you really don't know what T can be you are right. But usually I don't need so careful checking. BTW when you said about constrain - I thought you mentioned generic type constraint - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: yes, I meant generic type constraint. Concretely, you have to have `where T:class` in order to be able to use `as T`. Also, `T` does not represent the entity type, but the attribute type, which can be `int` as well (therefore not obeying the `class` constraint)

Comment: @w0lf you are right. I have updated my answer according to your note.

Comment: I'd prefer not to cast but I'm guessing there's not much to do, if we're to make it generic. Would it be a good idea to `try/catch` it? Just in case?

Comment: @AndreasJohansson KISS Keep stupid simple. To my mind author have to know what he has in Entity. I never don't try to predict everything. Because easy to fix crash on testing session than investigate strange behavior and parse logs trying to figure out what is going on production..

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change the signature of the method in *three* places, because you also have to add the generic parameter:

```
private T GetValue<T>(Entity entity, String attribute, T substitute)
```

*Within* the method, there's no real need for any complex coding; replacing your current occurrences of `string` or `int`, respectively, with `T`, should suffice. (Note that the `as` operator can only be applied if you restrict `T` to reference types - which you probably don't want to do, because `int` is a value type).

Note that there are two issues with this method that you might consider drawbacks:

- This generic method will support "all the types possible", but it will also support any types *impossible* (users are free to specify whatever type they like for `T`, and there is no way to restrict `T` while still supporting both `string` and `int`.
- You cannot specify arbitrary default substitute values for each type. What you can do is declare a default value for `substitute`, namely `default(T)`, but at least for `string`, that is not an empty string, but `null`.

Comment: Why do I need to add the `<T>` after the method's name? Isn't it implied by the type specified by the input parameter `substritute`?

Comment: @AndreasJohansson: Because otherwise, the generic parameter does not exist. Like any other parameter, generic parameters need to be declared, too. Without that, `T` is just an undeclared identifier and will yield a compiler error.

Comment: Oh, right! I thought it was retrieved implicitly based on the type you shove in into the parameters. But I see why that's a no-go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change method signature, you can write a generic function and call it from all of these non generic versions.

```
private String GetStringValue(...){
    return GetValue<String>(...);
}
```

By the way, you are looking for [Generic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

For e.g (from msdn)

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
{
    T temp;
    temp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = temp;
}

...

Swap<int>(ref a, ref b);
```

or just

```
Swap(ref a, ref b); //type int is infered based on type of arguements and method signature
```

Answer (score 1):

What class is `Entity`? Assuming it's a custom class, make it also generic, then this works:

```
private T Get<T>(Entity<T> entity, T attribute, T substitute = default(T))
{
    if (entity.Contains(attribute))
        return entity[attribute];
    return substitute;
}
```

You can retrieve the value in this way:

```
var entity = new Entity<string>();
string val = Get<string>(entity, "attr", "subst");
```

Comment: `Entity` is a standard class in SDK for Dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your `Entity<T>` class:

```
public class Entity<T>
{
    // TODO: implement
    public T this[string i] { get; set; }

    // TODO: implement
    internal bool Contains(string attribute)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // TODO: implement
    // other properties and methods       
}
```

And you may use a generic method:

```
private T GetStringValue<T>(Entity<T> entity, String attribute, T substitute = default(T))
{
    if (entity.Contains(attribute))
        return entity[attribute];
    return substitute;
}
```

Comment: `Entity` is not mine. It's a part of the SDK. Sadly. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to generalize the code inside a method I would absolutely recommend to use it in a generic way. It makes the class smaller, better readable and you just have to change one method if requirements change. Your method looks like it can be made generic easily.

```
private T GetIntValue<T>(Entity entity, String attribute, T substitute = default(T))
{
    if(entity.Contains(attribute))
        return (T)entity[attribute];
    return substitute;
}
```

If there would be some more logic to execute you could also use a dictionary with functions for the different types:

```
private IDictionary<Type, Func<Entity, string, object>> actions;

private void InitActions()
{
    actions = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Entity, string, object>>
        {
            {
                typeof (string), (entity, attribute) =>
                    {
                        // this could be your custom code for string
                        return entity[attribute];
                    }
            },
            {
                typeof (int), (entity, attribute) =>
                    {
                        // this could be your custom code for int
                        return entity[attribute];
                    }
            }
        };
}

private T GetIntValue<T>(Entity entity, String attribute, T substitute = default(T))
{
    if (entity.Contains(attribute) && actions.ContainsKey(typeof (T)))
    {
        Func<Entity, string, object> action = actions[typeof (T)];
        return (T)action(entity, attribute);
    }
    return substitute;
}
```